# difficult HTML, JavaScript, CSS grid page

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid

FYI, This is a simplified/generic example of what I'm working on.  I'm just looking for the HTML, JavaScript, and/or CSS that can make this work. I'd prefer that this can be done without any javascript library.  Also, the page will be built based on data loaded from a database. This only needs to work in newer IE/Firefox browsers.

I need to create a web page that has a grid of fixed size "cells" on it, each cell will be 150 pixels by 150 pixels.  Here is sample 6x3 grid, but my grids will vary in size (4x10 or 3x5, etc. as per the database data):

```
-------------------------------------
|     |     |     |     |     |     |
|     |     |     |     |     |     |
|     |     |     |     |     |     |
-------------------------------------
|     |     |     |     |     |     |
|     |     |     |     |     |     |       6x3 grid of "cells"
|     |     |     |     |     |     |
-------------------------------------
|     |     |     |     |     |     |
|     |     |     |     |     |     |
|     |     |     |     |     |     |
-------------------------------------
```

each of these cells will need the following:

**1)** contain a "main" image that is 150 pixels by 150 pixels.  This image will need to be changed in the browser, hopefully using CSS sprites if possible.  I'd like to stick all of these images into a single file and crop down to what is needed in each cell.

**2)** When the mouse is over a "Cell", an overlay of click-able images will display.  In the sample below I use letters, but the images will not be letters, more like icons.  These clicks need to be able to run a different per image javascript function (so a click on the "A" image will run function A, while a click on "F" will run function F, etc).  Images will be dependent on database info, so for different cells, some will be included and other not.  Their position within the cell will always be fixed and controlled.  Here is what a single cell might look with the images (letters) over top:

```
---------
|A  B  C|
|D  E  F|     a single cell where all overlay images appear
|G  H  I|
---------

---------
|A     C|
|   E   |     a single cell where only some overlay images appear
|G      |
---------
```

**3)** free text wrapping and centered within the cell.  It would be best if this free text was above the main image #1 and below the click-able images #2, but if it was on top of everything than that would be OK too. There will be a reasonable length limit on this text, so scrolling beyond the 150px x 150px should not be an issue, but it will need to wrap.

For the record, this is not homework! and HTML/javascript/CSS is certainly not my strength.  I have been working at this for a while and have seen/worked with many examples of how to do various components of this.  I've yet to find anything that can work when everything id put together.

Comment: This may be a job for display: table (and related display styles), especially since you are targeting newer browsers which support these styles. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-display

Comment: Are tables an option by any chance?  Say, each tablecell (that is  generated as per the database data) has its own div (and possibly own css) that can be worked with.  Just a thought

Comment: @Gobbledigook, yes, I'm completely fine with tables.

Comment: @KM. Could you take a look at my solution and let me know if something isn't as you expected.

Comment: You have no need for tables to do this.

Comment: @Rob actually.. you do, it won't work in IE7 (real IE7, not IE8 in I7 compatibility mode)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Personally I think tables are the devil, so here is something more like what I would do that uses floated divs:

http://jsfiddle.net/gbcd6/11/

You could easily swap out the text content for images, or add background images through CSS, as well as call separate JS functions based on the one-nine class each "control" div has.

**EDIT:**

[Here is the most current version of the solution](http://jsfiddle.net/gbcd6/21/), which does include an actual table rather than using `display: table-cell`, as well as additional example markup for images and wrapping, and a basic Javascript example. This was done to fix an issue with older browser support, and to meet KM's requirements. Though the overall structure is still pretty much the same as the original fiddle.

Comment: I changed: `<p>Background.</p>` to `<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy gray dog!</p>` and it only displays `The quick brown` in the block, with the remaining parts below in multiple rows

Comment: Ah, that's because I vertically centered my short placeholder text by setting the line-height to 150 pixels. If you change the line-height to something more reasonable, it will look fine. Such as http://jsfiddle.net/gbcd6/12/

Comment: also, if the screen isn't wide enough, the cells wrap.

Comment: Yes, I actually considered that an advantage of using the floated div method. If you don't want them to wrap, simply add a wrapper div of whatever width you want around them. Or if, say, you want three per row, you could set the wrapper div to 450px (+ margins), and then they will wrap after every three. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gbcd6/16/

Comment: Added a background color to the wrap so you can see its boundaries more clearly: http://jsfiddle.net/gbcd6/17/

Comment: how can I get an image into the cell under `<p>Background.</p>`?

Comment: Add it as a `background-image` in the `div.cell` CSS, or in an inline style.

Comment: @jblasco nice one, just want to add that tables can be your friend, sometimes, too :-)

Comment: @ptriek Oh, I know tables can be quite useful, I don't mean to damn them entirely, heh. Even in my solution I used a `display: table-cell` to easily vertically align the background text, because tables are still the king when it comes to vertical alignment without help from JS. Even if I think in general they're not nearly as flexible.

Comment: When I try this (latest version jsfiddle.net/gbcd6/18) in IE 8 (works fine in Firefox), I don't get the "overlay" divs when I mouse over the "cell".  also, the `Background.` text is not vertically centered, it is on the top of the "cell".  Any ideas?

Comment: I'll take a look at it in IE8, just need to flip over to a computer that still has it.

Comment: In my IE8 it looks and works pretty much the same as Chrome/IE9 to me: the overlay divs show, and the background text is vertically centered. Even in compatibility mode (which emulates IE7) it's still somewhat decent: just the background text isn't centered, but the overlays still show on hover. Could you post a screenshot of what you're seeing on hover, maybe?

Comment: For IE 8, this runs fine in the jsfiddle.net page, but when I paste into a local file the mouse over DIVs don't ever appear.  when I go to http://jsfiddle.net/gbcd6/18/ and paste the exact CSS and html text only into this file: `<HTML>
<HEAD>
<style>
 <!--css here-->
</style>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<!--html here-->
</BODY>
</HTML>` for IE 8, I don't get the pink "overlay" divs when I mouse over the blue balloon "cell". also, the Background text is not vertically centered, it is on the top of the "cell".  do I need to include anything else into the html css?  Works fine in FF

Comment: It's really strange it won't work in your IE8. If i open [this](http://www.thebackoffice.be/tmp/fiddle.html) in my IE8 (not IETester, true IE8 install) i see [this](http://www.thebackoffice.be/tmp/ie8.png). Have you tried on another machine? (mouse pointer is not included in the screenshot)

Comment: Hm, when I tried a local copy in my IE8, it works fine, as well. Did you try declaring a doctype? EDIT: Yep, I can confirm that removing the doctype declaration from my local copy breaks the page in IE8. Add one at the top of the page, like `<!DOCTYPE html>`, or one of the HTML4 doctypes, and you should be good to go.

Comment: @jblasco tables are evil, indeed. (see my last comment in my answer)

Comment: when I run: http://www.thebackoffice.be/tmp/fiddle.html the hover overlayer appears.  comparing this web page with mine, I determined that the first line was causing the problem.  Using this, it works in both browsers: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN">`  while I was using one with HTML and not XHTML.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I was talking about when I was referring to doctype. Though personally I wouldn't use XHTML transitional. What was the one you were using, that didn't work?

Comment: @jblasco, I was using `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">`, which did not work.

Comment: the text is still not centered vertically in IE.  It is at http://www.thebackoffice.be/tmp/fiddle.html but not in my local version.  I viewed the source and pasted into my file and it still isn't centered.  I DIFFed the two versions and they are the same, any ideas?

Comment: Is your IE opening the page in compatibility mode, or using different security settings when viewing a local file? Also when you say "running locally," do you mean just opening the .htm document in the browser, or running through IIS/Apache or something similar?

Comment: Also out of morbid curiosity, could you see if this runs fine locally in your IE8 http://jsfiddle.net/jblasco/gbcd6/19/

Comment: how can I tell what mode IE is running it in?  local means putting it on an apache machine in my local private network.  "morbid curiosity", the tables seem to fix the vertical alignment.

Comment: Open the developer tools by pressing F12, and then it should say in the top right somewhere what browser/document modes it's running in. Also if a combination div/table solution does seem to work reliably cross-browser, then you could just go with that.

Comment: browser mode: IE8, document mode: IE7 standards.

Comment: Yeah, on mine it's running with IE8 standards. IE7 standards means it's running under compatibility mode, which emulates IE7. You can stick this meta tag in the header to force IE to run the page at the highest document mode available: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`. However, I'd be interested to see if the page looks correct without the table in IE7, then. I'm not sure how far back in the past you're planning to support.

Comment: The XHTML doctype shown by KM above is incorrect and puts you into quirks mode. Use this one: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: In fact, the HTML doctype shown by KM is not wrong but not up to date either.

Comment: Updated the answer to include the latest revision of the fiddle, where I also added a basic Javascript example.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for a large table, indeed.

And it's not so very hard to accomplish, at least if this is more or less what you need:

http://jsfiddle.net/gNBSc/4/

(i'm a bit bored, today :-)

Comment: thanks, this looks promising!  I took this code down to my PC and was messing around with it.  I doubled up the row to make a 2x6 grid and the mouse over does not work on the new row.  When I try to replace the "http://placehold.it/50x50" with a local image it still retains the "50 x 50".  Also, I couldn't get `onclick="alert('wow!');"` to work from the "50x50" images.

Comment: updated my answer with new fiddle, with extra row (don't see why this wouldn't be working locally) and with onclick. what do you mean by 'retains the 50x50'?

Comment: with the new example, I still don't get a mouse over to work on the second row.  when I said 'retains the 50x50', even though I edited the `src="http://placehold.it/50x50"` to be `src="LocalFile.png"` I still see the `50x50` graphic.

Comment: second row: strange, it works perfectly for me (and as mentioned before, there's nothing in the code that could trigger this) / 50x50-image: now that's even stranger. try clearing cache, try other browsers?

Comment: u're welcome, jblasco's solution was a bit better than mine (though believe me, tables aren't the devil, they're just a bit evil sometimes).

Comment: when going to http://jsfiddle.net/gNBSc/4/ it works fine in IE 8, but not Firefox 8.  In FF the mouse over overlay does not display for the second row.

Comment: mh. that's verry strange. fyi, i posted a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522979/firefox-divhover-only-working-on-first-row) about this.

Comment: i'm afraid @jblasco is your only option, it cannot be done with tables without loosing the vertical centering. so 'm hoping you can get it working in IE7...

Comment: @ptriek it CAN be done without actual tables, with vertical centering.

Answer (score 1):

I just came up with this solution http://jsfiddle.net/LNw3G. It's a *mix* between the use of `table` and `div` elements.

I also added an image *sprite*, positioning through class names *left*, *center*, *right*, *top* and *bottom*  (so you don't have to edit all the image positions in your css), and javascript for parsing specific calls depending on the anchor `class`.

This is an example of the HTML for a single cell. `cell-wrap cell1` contains the elements and positions the background image sprite, the table vertically aligns the text, and `cell` contains the controlled positioned images wrapped into `image` divs.

```
<div class="cell-wrap cell1">
    <table class="content">
        <tr>
            <td>Connection is not correct</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="cell hidden">
        <div class="image left top">
            <a href="#linkA" class="linkA"><img src="http://goo.gl/wNDMe"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="image right top">
            <a href="#linkB" class="linkB"><img src="http://goo.gl/wNDMe"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="image left bottom">
            <a href="#linkC" class="linkC"><img src="http://goo.gl/wNDMe"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the significant javascript code, which filters anchors containing class names with `link` to the desired specific functions:

```
$(function() {
    $(".cell a").click(function(e) {
        if ($(this).attr("class").match(/link(.)(\\s[\\b]*)?/)) {
            var param = $(this).attr("class").replace(/(.*\s)*link(.).*$/, "$2");
            doThings(param);
        }
    });
});

function doThings(param) {
    switch (param) {
    case 'A':
        //specific 'A' functions
        break;
    case 'B':
        //specific 'B' functions
        break;
    default:
        //default functions
        break;
}
```

It has been tested IE7+, FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera.

Ps: There is a workaround for **IE6** you can use for this example, consisting in adding an specific *hover.htc* file and the css line `body { behavior: url(hover.htc); }` ([more detailed here](http://www.devinrolsen.com/fix-css-pseudo-hover)) to simulate hover effect on *non-anchor* elements.

Ps: Be careful with the `<!DOCTYPE` declaration. If you leave empty spaces, maybe something like this `<!  DOCTYPE`, IE7 may treat it as non valid jumping into quirks mode (while testing, it drove me nuts!).

Answer (score 1):

Gave it a try, you can find the attempt [here](http://kodu.ut.ee/~vahurr/grid/). Let me know if misunderstood something. Tested in FF5, newest Chrome, IE8 (and in IE7 compatibility mode). Uses no libraries, doesn't need to actually be a grid (depends on the width that you can set in CSS) and gives you the index of the image and the button that was clicked. Oh, and the grid should be easily generatable (based on your DB) in PHP etc.

**EDIT**:
The text is now vertically-aligned also.

Comment: @Nacho and the text is now vertically aligned.

Comment: Check IE7, text is not aligned vertically

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/F37qs/1/

Pretty much an example of what you would want with

1. floating div's... Allowing custom "table sizes";
2. Reactive rollover "abit randomized"; and lastly,
3. Centralized content (see the centralized text in each grid);

Note : You can adjust the various number of rows / cols you want. =)

Comment: I think the OP did not intend for the table elements to blink up randomly, but that there is different looking table elements.

Comment: @kontur, =/ the question didnt state the logic detirmining which element to show / hide... so i had it randomized, to show it is possible to show / hide any combination he can toss at it. =P