# Firefox: div:hover only working on first row

Tags: html, css, firefox

- I have a very simple table, containing a div that shows some smaller inner divs upon rollover. Just plain old CSS2, nothing fancy at all.
- Works as expected in Chrome & Safari.
- **In Firefox 8, however, the :hover only works on the first TR - while the second TR is *exactly* the same.**
- Code has no validation errors.
- Any ideas what might be causing this behaviour?
- Working jsfiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/gNBSc/9/

Comment: I'm assuming this is for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477338/difficult-html-javascript-css-grid-page

Comment: @Wex your assumption is correct!

Comment: I think your selector `$("img")` should be `$(".img")`.

Comment: @Wex yeah, i just changed the img's to divs - but anyway, the js isn't relevant to the question - i'm going to leave it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox is not taking kindly to your applying `position:relative` to the `tr`s themselves (I am not sure why, did not have time to look it up). This has the effect of *all* your `div.hover` elements being stacked on the first table row (see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hTS7h/1/), added borders to make it clear).

As a workaround, you can wrap the contents of each `tr` in a `div`, and apply `position:relative` to that `div` instead of the `tr`.

Comment: Apparently FF is doing things right, and other browsers fail - I found this quote: "This is because according to CSS 2.1, the effect of position: relative on table elements is undefined."

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is related to this css definition, you are positioning ALL your "hover" items to absolute and defining top 0px.

```
div.hover {
    height:150px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    width:150px;
}
```

Simply changing the positioning to `relative` will fix the issue you are having, then you could position your "some text" instead.  or rethink your structure of course.

```
div.hover {
    height:150px;
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    width:150px;
}
```

But for your question specifically, the above class is the culprit.

Comment: interesting. changing to relative fixes it indeed, but i need the vertical alignment of the text (can contain more lines). and i'm not sure if that's doable with your solution...